# Process.Start - How to send the launched executable to the back (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Is it possible to make a process launched with `Process.Start` to be launched and sent to the "back of the screen" e.g. behind all other open windows on the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View the [ProcessWindowStyle Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx) for available options:

> an application may initialize a new window to the **Hidden** style while it customizes the window's appearance, and then make the window style Normal.

You can start your process at minimized state, for example:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "Myapplication.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized; // or Hidden here
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set [`ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) to start the process without creating a new window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported directly in the .NET API.

As I see it, there are few options:

1. Start the process and make its window hidden (the window will not be drawn to screen).

   This can be done with this overload: [`Process.Start Method (ProcessStartInfo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)

   Pass in the WindowStyle "Hidden" in the `ProcessStartInfo` object.
2. Creating the process and then immediately grabbing its window handle (`HWND`) and playing with it.

   This is less "clean" and may require some Win32 messing, doesn't seem like the right option.

It all depends on what exactly you're after.

Comment: Obtaining the window handle (`HWND`) and using the `SetWindowPos` function to, well, set the window position doesn't seem "unclean" or messy to me. In fact, that's **exactly** what I'd do. I'd be concerned about how some of the other methods will interact with applications that are *expecting* to be able to create/show a window. `SetWindowPos` with the `HWND_BOTTOM` flag is never going to be a problem.

Comment: All of this will occur after the process has been created, isn't there a risk that the window will pop momentarily and disappear?